# Python Pandas Importing XML File

Tags: python, pandas

Situation:

I have a ".txt" file that contains xml data.

I want to read this file in python.

I am using the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("name_of_file.txt", sep='lasagna', header=None)
```

The file contains 3242 rows. The dataframe contains 3181 rows.

I made my the sep value equal to lasagna because I wanted the delimiter to not actually work and import everything as 1 column.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Does your file contain xml or csv data? You've said xml in your description but you're using the `read_csv` function to parse the file.

Comment: And then could you provide samples of that .txt file..